# How to properly call handler method in C#?

Tags: c#, methods, parameters, handler

I am having issues with the following method below -GetTransactionsCompletedEventHandler. I am attempting to pass the necessary arguments to it, but it is also asking for more parameters in a format I am unfamiliar with.

It is asking for GetTransactionsCompletedEventHandler(object[] results(object, GetTransactionsCompletedEventArgs)target)

Can anyone point me in the right direction of how to properly call this method?

```
static object[] results;
static Exception exception;
static bool cancelled;
static object userState;
TransactionService.GetTransactionsCompletedEventArgs test1 = new TransactionService.GetTransactionsCompletedEventArgs(results, exception, cancelled, userState);

public void testMethod()
{
}
static List<string> orderlist;
public object testObject;
public void getTransactions()
{
    TransactionService.GetTransactionsCompletedEventHandler test = new TransactionService.GetTransactionsCompletedEventHandler(testObject, test1);
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with this event handler?

Comment: Always check [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transaction.transactioncompleted%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if you're unsure about a class.

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? if so what are they? All I can think of at the moment is to try and create test1 within scope of the getTransactions method rather than as a global variable.

Comment: The only class that should invoke handlers is the owner. This doesn't look like that case - why are you trying to invoke the handler *manually*? It seems like you're making some intermediate layer between two pieces of code, but why would you do it like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the helpful comments. I found that I was going about this incorrectly, and should just instantiate a service, and can get transactions in this way.

```
TransactionService.TransactionService _service = new TransactionService.TransactionService();
TransactionService.TransactionSearchParameters _params = new TransactionService.TransactionSearchParameters();
TransactionService.Transaction []list = _service.GetTransactions(_params);
```